# Adjust sequence position of barcode scanning result

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I've been improve our warehouse record method by barcode scanning. 
But the problem defaut scanning result inside excel format is after scan cursor will move to below cell ( ex : A1 to A2 to A3 etc).

Requirement record data, sequence of scanning result is A1, B1, A2, B2, A3, B3 etc.
If someone could help me with this I would be eternally grateful. Thanks!

Comment: This is probably a scanner setting. Or the data import from the scanner.

Comment: It would be helpful to have more details. You haven't explained if this is functionality of Excel or the scanner you are referring to. So, does the scanner invoke a carriage return (press enter) after it scans? What have you tried or researched? What scanner are you using?

Comment: Purpose of this record for auto calulation data with sequence keyin data as follow : Cell A1 to Cell B1 than next data from cell A2 to Cell B2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell Excel a direction to move after enter is pressed (a very common behavior for barcode scanners.)  If you go into Excel's "Advanced" options, you can set "After Pressing Enter, Move Selection:" to your desired direction, which in this case, is Right.

Comment: Issue being the keypress should go right, down/left, right, down/left

Answer (score 0):

Barcode scanners can typically be setup to send a tab, return, or nothing after sending whatever the barcode data was. It sounds like it's currently set to send an enter key.

**Step 1:** Setup your barcode scanner to send tab instead of enter. (How to do this will depend on your scanner.) If you can't make this change, then change Excel's enter key behavior so it goes right instead of down. You can search online for how to change this setting but, briefly, it is File > Options > Advanced > Editing Options section > After pressing enter, move selection > Right

**Step 2:** Make  it so the user can only select columns A and B using sheet protection.

1. Select columns A & B. Right-click on them and choose Format Cells.
2. In the Protection tab, make sure the Locked box is unchecked.
   [image: Unlock Cells]
3. In the Review ribbon, click Protect Sheet.
   [image: Protect Sheet Button]
4. Uncheck "Select locked cells" and click OK. (You can also set a password here if you don't want them messing with other cells without a password.)
   [image: Protect Sheet Settings]

Now they will be unable to select anything besides what's in columns A and B. After entering data in `A1`, it will move to `B1` (either through a tab key or an altered enter key behavior). After entering data in `B1`, it would normally want to go to `C1` but it's not allowed so it wraps around to the next row and ends up at `A2`. (If you test this behavior on a blank sheet, it may not work right since moves between cells in the used range and it doesn't see all the blank rows at the bottom as being used. Enter data as you go along and it'll work correctly.)